# Exclude a directory form redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added RewriteCond which should ommit the admin directory from re-directing. However it keeps on sendin URLS like this

http://www.site.tld/admin/software/windows/edit/148 to http://www.site.tld/help.php

What am I doing wrong here? Been trying to solve this for a while now...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 301 /en/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /windows/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /home/os/(.*) /os/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/software/add_version/(.*) http://www.site.tld/help.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/edit/(.*) http://www.site.tld/help.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/software/edit/(.*) http://www.site.tld/help.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/software/add_image/(.*) http://www.site.tld/help.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/` will only match the `/admin/` folder. Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/.*$
```